# How to differentiate between Vista SP1 and Server 2008 at install

Tags: windows-vista, installation, wix, operating-system, windows-server-2008

I have a Wix installer which should be allowed to run on Windows Server 2008 but not on Vista. According to Microsoft's [Operating System Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370556(VS.85).aspx) page, this is not possible using the parameters they provide for this purpose (VersionNT and WindowsBuild).

Has anyone solved this problem or know how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
<Condition Message="This application is only supported on Windows Server 2008, or higher.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR (VersionNT >= 600 AND MsiNTProductType > 1)]]>
</Condition>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that such a check can be easily bypassed by someone simply editing the MSI with Orca, so unless there are technical limitations (e.g. even if they get it installed, certain services will only be present on the Server OS) I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: Good point, but I think making them do that is enough of a barrier to entry that they'll be aware they're running on an OS that's 'not supported' ;)